# query slower with prefetch related than without?

Tags: python, django

This is the pseudocode of my models

```
Offer
    match = FK(Match)

Odds
    offer = FK(Offer, related_name='odds')

test1 = "[o.odds.all() for o in Offer.objects.filter(match__id=123)]"
test2 = "[o.odds.all() for o in Offer.objects.filter(match__id=123).prefetch_related('odds')]"
timeit.timeit(test1, number=1000)
>>> 3.078
timeit.timeit(test2, number=1000)
>>> 11.794
```

I thought that when prefetching the odds, displaying them would be no problem at all - then it turns out that it's actually slower to prefetch them. Am I doing something wrong, or do I simply not understand the use of `prefetch_related`?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I am going to query for `o.odds.latest()` and take use of that information only, and I'm simply trying to optimize my query. I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around `select_related` and `prefetch_related`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using an FK you could use a select_related rather than prefetch_related and see how this compares:

> select_related works by creating an SQL join and including the fields of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason, select_related gets the related objects in the same database query. However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from joining across a ‘many’ relationship, select_related is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
>
> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by select_related. It also supports prefetching of GenericRelation and GenericForeignKey.

Comment: This would be correct if he was calling `prefetch_related("match")`.

Comment: Yes indeed, but since he is trying to find the optimal query he could reverse it and filter from there, otherwise RAW SQL.

Comment: I agree with @CraigLabenz - I am using the reverse of the FK.

Comment: Do you have a way I could optimize that query usign select_related? That would be perfect.

Comment: I don't have my sandbox right here, but can you check this:
`test3 = [o.offer for o in Odds.objects.select_related('offer','offer__match').filter(offer__match__id=123)]`

Answer (score 2):

If you examine the queries Django executes, you'll see that `prefetch_related()` leads to an additional query with a `WHERE IN (ids)` clause. Those values are then mapped back to the original object in Python, preventing additional database load.

Calling `prefetch_related()` on unrestrained `all()` QuerySets against your entire database can be *very* costly, especially if your tables are large. However, if you are working with smaller sets of data thanks to a meaningful `filter(key=value)` addition to your original QuerySet, `prefetch_related()` will reduce N trips to the database down to 1 trip to the database. This can lead to a drastic performance increase.

And as a side note -- don't run `prefetch_related("odds")` unless you need that data. Your test isn't making use of the extra information, but it's still doing the extra work to fetch it. There's no free lunch :)

Comment: I a going to use the data, so I guess accessing a value in an arbitrary `odds` object would make more sense for the test itself. Although, I just ran the newly proposed test and I saw no performance increase on that either.