# Django Rest Framework large number of queries for nested relationship

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

**My problem**

I have a large number of nested model serializers (5 levels deep) via one-to-many relationships. The total query time is not that high according to django debug toolkit - maybe 100ms, but it takes about 6s of cpu time to run due to the many hundreds of times the database is being hit per query.

The problem is, 3 of those tables are huge, with millions of rows. As such, whenever I run 'prefetch_related' for anything it takes far longer to execute, sometimes minutes. select_related isn't an option, as they are all one-to-many.

Imagine something like a pedometer that takes steps, and also ties multiple environment readings and accelerometer readings to a step.

**Example Schema**

```
Person
id
name

Pedometer
id
name
owner(Person)

Step
id
info
timestamp
pedometer

Environment_Readings
id
pressure
step

Accelerometer_Readings
id
force
step
```

**What I want to achieve**

So I want to select all people > an array of their pedometers (often multiple) > an array of all steps they have taken in the last minute > array of environment readings and array of accelerometer readings.

I am not seeing a way to prefetch environment_readings or accelerometer_readings as neither have a timestamp. The only ones that can be prefetched appear to be pedometer and step. And for some reason prefetching pedometer seems to slow it down.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179934/query-slower-with-prefetch-related-than-without

Comment: You are using all the people, so it will probably have a lot of info to retrieve. Do you have many persons? consider pagination then.

Comment: No, the number of persons isn't the issue. The performance I am getting is when I'm selecting about 50 people.

Comment: Relationships are too big, so for every person you may be retrieving millions of records.

Comment: "I am not seeing a way to prefetch environment_readings or accelerometer_readings as neither have a timestamp." Why does timestamp matter in the prefetch?

Comment: timestamp would just be a way to limit the number of objects returned in the prefetch queryset.